# How to put these 3 pictures to the left and 3 pictures to the right?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, frontend

I have 6 images in a row and I want to position 3 to the left and 3 to the right.  I tried display: flex and float:left however it just bumped up all the content beneath the section tab up overlapping displays.  How do I split the 6 images in half with text in the middle?

```
<section className="open-text">
    <h1>
        <br/>
        <img className="move_to_left" height="70" width="70"  alt="usda_icon" src= "images/FDAT.gif"/>
        <img className="move_to_left" height="70" width="70"  alt="usda_icon" src= "images/usdaT.gif"/>
        <img className="move_to_left" height="80" width="80"  alt="usda_icon" src= "images/dermT.png"/>
        ***String of Text***
        <img className="move_to_right" height="90" width="90"  alt="usda_icon" src= "images/HypoT2.jpg"/>
        <img className="move_to_right" height="100" width="100"  alt="usda_icon" src= "images/ssl.png"/>
        <img className="move_to_right" height="80" width="80"  alt="usda_icon" src= "images/para2.gif"/>        
        <br/>
    </h1>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.open-text > h1 {
    color: #1e3a87;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    margin-top: 12.5px !important;
    height: 10rem;    
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    mix-blend-mode: color-burn;    
    display: flex !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
}
.open-text > h1 {
    /*border: 4px solid red;*/
    /*display: flex;*/
    /*justify-content: space-around;*/
    /*float: left;*/
}
.open-text > h1:nth-child(odd) {
    border: 1px solid red;
    /*float: right;*/
}
```

Comment: That structure doesn't make much sense for what you want. Why don't you create 3 columns instead? And why are the images inside an `<h1>`?

Comment: Do you want the sets of 3 images stacked vertically or horizontally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use class="" for class names in html

It can be done using flexbox by seeting the parent to align center items, then you set each item to float accordingly inside your flex box, align-self : start for the left ones, and align-self:end; for the right ones.

Here's an example of how i would ghave done it :

```css
.open-text {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
.open-text h1 {
color: #1e3a87;    
display: flex;
align-items: center;
font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
justify-content:space-around;
}
.open-text img {
margin:5px;
}
.open-text .move_to_left {
  align-self:start;
}
.open-text .move_to_right {
  align-self:end;
}
.open-text .string_of_text {
  align-self:center;
}
```

```html
<section class="open-text">
    <h1>
        <br/>
        <img class="move_to_left" height="70" width="70"  alt="usda_icon" src= "https://via.placeholder.com/70"/>
        <img class="move_to_left" height="70" width="70"  alt="usda_icon" src= "https://via.placeholder.com/70"/>
        <img class="move_to_left" height="70" width="70"  alt="usda_icon" src= "https://via.placeholder.com/70"/>
      <span class="string_of_text">***String of Text***</span>
        <img class="move_to_right" height="70" width="70"  alt="usda_icon" src= "https://via.placeholder.com/70"/>
        <img class="move_to_right" height="70" width="70"  alt="usda_icon" src= "https://via.placeholder.com/70"/>
        <img class="move_to_right" height="70" width="70"  alt="usda_icon" src= "https://via.placeholder.com/70"/>        
        <br/>
    </h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, perhaps this would work for you?

Keep in mind that I've replaced `className` with `class` so that the sample below works - remember to revert this if you're rendering this out via JSX:

```css
.open-text > h1 {
    height: 10rem;    
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center; /* Cause "vertical" center alignment */
    flex-direction:row; /* Spread children of h1 along the x-axis */
    display: flex;
}

.open-text > h1 > img {
    flex:1;  /* This causes the image elements to squish down so that
                text comfortably fits */

}
```

```html
<section class="open-text">
    <h1>
        <img class="move_to_left" height="70" width="70"  alt="usda_icon" src= "https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
        <img class="move_to_left" height="70" width="70"  alt="usda_icon" src= "https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
        <img class="move_to_left" height="80" width="80"  alt="usda_icon" src= "https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
        ***String of Text***
        <img class="move_to_right" height="90" width="90"  alt="usda_icon" src= "https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
        <img class="move_to_right" height="100" width="100"  alt="usda_icon" src= "https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>
        <img class="move_to_right" height="80" width="80"  alt="usda_icon" src= "https://via.placeholder.com/150"/>        
        <br/>
    </h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this is by using the inline-block display property. Here is an example using some colored divs, but it will work the same on your images.

```
display: inline-block;
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/chnbL179/

Comment: This is for a large container with 100% width not a small one.